# Chainload windows.img in grub2

Tags: windows, grub2, dual-boot

I normally use my Windows system on a infrequent basis making it more advantageous to run it in a virtualbox. However, I want to do something that goes beyond the limits of my Virtualbox.

For this reason I want to create an .img of my Windows virtual hdd and boot the windows system using the image.

The problem I currently have: I can't find any grub2 parameters making this possible? I have seen examples on different Linux distributions or .iso files but not booting Windows from .img

1 question I'm also asking myself: what about the changes on the image? Are they written to .img as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Windows does not understand the concept of using an `.img` file as its boot disk. No GRUB parameters can help you here: the problem is making Windows understand your scheme after GRUB has handed over control of the hardware to the Windows bootloader.

`ipxe.org` includes [`wimboot`](http://ipxe.org/wimboot), a Windows bootloader that can be started like a Linux kernel. It can boot Windows PE (a Windows preinstallation/rescue environment) using Windows's native `.wim` image file format loaded into RAM. As a result, your system disk size will be limited by your available RAM, and any changes to the RAM disk will be lost when Windows is shut down. I mention this just in case your requirement that "goes beyond the limits of VirtualBox" might be satisfiable within a Windows PE environment.

If you don't know about `.wim` images or setting up a Windows PE environment, that's an entire separate question which would probably be best placed in [Super User.se](https://superuser.com).

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Windows PE is not an option in any way. I need a fullblown Windows installation and I need a lot of video ram (128MB in virtualbox is not enough). I don't want to run the app using wine as I mostly had bad experiences with it.